# Community Promotion Ads?

Tags: discussion

Does our [non-beta status](https://outdoors.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1533/4079) change how our Community Promotion Ads work?

A new post at [DBA.se](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3284/21924) got me wondering if we should do something simular.

Looks like we did something in 2018 [Suggest community promotion ads 2018](https://outdoors.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1126/4079)

Comment: There is now an option, per a new meta post [Community Promotion Ads — 2020](https://outdoors.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1608/4079)  I don't want to edit this question or post a new answer and distract from the new post

Answer (score 2):

1. Those aren't enabled for this site, and they get very few clicks anyways.
2. The png is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fGuXb.png) if people want to change their avatars which shows the image in plenty of places. Changing usernames also brings light to the issue in plenty of places too.
3. There is at least one effort to move  [and recreate the system elsewhere](https://forum.codidact.org/), that's at least worth thinking about.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know who has to approve of Community Promotion Ads (CPA).  But in the current phase of The Mess, where everything that can be said has been said several times over, and  considering that Monica has retained legal counsel, we need to keep the issue visible and keep the pressure on without being counterproductive.  If a discreet -- but not too discreet -- CPA is one such tactic, I am all for it.